# Вводное слово

Tags: морфология

Является ли наречие "вкратце" вводным словом? Например, что-то объясняется-рекламируется, а потом звучит: "Вкратце_это уникальное приобретение..."

Answer (score 1):

"Вкратце" можно что-то изложить, передать, пересказать или рассказать. Это наречие чаще всего стоит при глаголе "говорения" и является обстоятельством. В качестве вводного оно как-то не смотрится и не слушается, хотя редкие примеры употребления его как вводного уже встречаются.  Лучше в Вашем случае употребить всё-таки "короче говоря".

Answer (score 0):

Вообще, "вкратце" - это "коротко", наречие, но оно может выступить как вводное слово в значении "короче говоря" (это та группа вводных слов, которая обозначает способ оформления мысли). Так что в приведенном Вами предложении слово "вкратце" вполне может выступить как вводное слово

Comment: Ага, спасибо)